# Magento 2.2 - How to Create a custom dynamic checkout form

Tags: checkout, magento2.2

I have to solve following situation and need some help for the way of the solution.

I have to create a custom checkout form, which input elements are defined in a db table. If the user has the related customer group, than I have to load the form fields and types and parse them as a new checkout form.

The fields are grouped so I want to use a fieldset for each of these.
In the fieldset I want to add the result entries ( table rows ) like
this:

```
foreach result as row:
row->FORMELEMT | row->DESCRIPTION | row->PRICE 
endforeach
```

And finally **a button.**

> So my question is, what is the best way to create a dynamic form like this?
>
> - Using a LayoutProzessor? But how can i add / create a custom Field where i can add the type of field, the description and the price?
> - Or do i have to use another way, directly with a KO Template and assign the Result Rows in a ConfigProvider, so i can get this in a KO Template?

Hope you understand the task.

Thanks for help,

Andre